# How to use yaml-cpp in a C++ program on Linux?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have recently decided to use yaml as my configuration file technology, and am writing a c++ linux application on OpenSuse 11.3.

The problem is that even after successfully installing cmake, compilling yaml-cpp as shown on the yaml-cpp docs page, I still can't compile the simple demo programs on the yaml-cpp page [here](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument).

For example, when I try to compile the the [monster.yaml and main.cpp example](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument#A_Complete_Example)

my compiler on issuing the command `gcc main.cpp`, it issues the following errors:

> main.cpp:24:25: error: ‘YAML’ does not name a type
>   main.cpp:24:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:24:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:24:35: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:30:25: error: ‘YAML’ does not name a type
>   main.cpp:30:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:30:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:30:35: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:35:25: error: ‘YAML’ does not name a type
>   main.cpp:35:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:35:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
>   main.cpp:35:35: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token

I tried changing the include directive from `#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"` to `#include <yaml.h>`, since I'd installed the yaml lib, but this didn't solve anything.

so what did I do wrong?

Here is the problematic code pasted from lines 24 to 40:

```
void operator >> (const YAML::Node& node, Vec3& v) {
   node[0] >> v.x;
   node[1] >> v.y;
   node[2] >> v.z;
}

void operator >> (const YAML::Node& node, Power& power) {
   node["name"] >> power.name;
   node["damage"] >> power.damage;
}

void operator >> (const YAML::Node& node, Monster& monster) {
   node["name"] >> monster.name;
   node["position"] >> monster.position;
   const YAML::Node& powers = node["powers"];
   for(unsigned i=0;i<powers.size();i++) {
      Power power;
      powers[i] >> power;
      monster.powers.push_back(power);
   }
}
```

And here is a dump of the output of the `sudo make install` after I run the `make` command:

```
[ 81%] Built target yaml-cpp
[ 96%] Built target run-tests
[100%] Built target parse
Install the project...
-- Install configuration:      "Release"                                                                                                                                              
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.so.0.2.6
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.so.0.2
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/aliasmanager.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/anchor.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/conversion.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/dll.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/emitfromevents.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/emitter.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/emittermanip.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/eventhandler.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/iterator.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/ltnode.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/mark.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/node.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/nodeimpl.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/nodereadimpl.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/nodeutil.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/noncopyable.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/null.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/ostream.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/parser.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/stlemitter.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/stlnode.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/traits.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/yaml.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/anchordict.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/graphbuilder.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/yaml-cpp.pc
```

Could there probably be some special directive / option that I have to append to the `gcc` command when compiling with libyaml? something like `gcc main.cpp -libyaml` ?

For more output from the compiler (`gcc version 4.5.0 20100604 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 160292] (SUSE Linux)`) :

```
/tmp/ccYltArL.o: In function `operator>>(YAML::Node const&, Monster&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::size() const'
/tmp/ccYltArL.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char,      std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to   `YAML::Parser::Parser(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `YAML::Node::Node()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x23e): undefined reference to    `YAML::Parser::GetNextDocument(YAML::Node&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29c): undefined reference to `std::cout'
```

and much more stuff than can *fit here*
, finally ending in:

```
/tmp/ccYltArL.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4YAML14BadDereferenceE[typeinfo for YAML::BadDereference]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for    __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/ccYltArL.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4YAML11KeyNotFoundE[typeinfo for YAML::KeyNotFound]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for  __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
/tmp/ccYltArL.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4YAML13InvalidScalarE[typeinfo for YAML::InvalidScalar]+0x0): more undefined references to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info' follow
/tmp/ccYltArL.o:(.rodata._ZTIN4YAML9ExceptionE[typeinfo for YAML::Exception]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::runtime_error'
/tmp/ccYltArL.o:(.eh_frame+0x18f): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

-- finally --

**Solved it** with Chris's soln (see below), though I actually found an even cleaner way of pre-loading 'custom' libraries, by using the `ldconfig` command to configure the library search path after i add the path to my libs into a `*.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`. See the [detailed guide here...](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/)

Comment: paste code from main.cpp line 24 30 and 35

Answer (score 10, accepted):

gcc isn't being instructed to look in /usr/local. You need to do it explicitly. Also, that really should be g++ and not gcc. So first make sure your include looks like this:

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
```

Then compile it like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lyaml-cpp -o testprogram main.cpp
```

Comment: This actually does compile the program properly, BUT when i try to run the executable with `./testprogram`, I get the run-time error: `./testprogram: error while loading shared libraries: libyaml-cpp.so.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: `$> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.so ./testprogram`

Comment: If the above line works, you'll need to add libyaml-cpp.so's path to your library search path. I don't remember how to do that, you'll need to google that one. The better way is that when you're compiling a program, have it install to /usr and not /usr/local.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the run-time error too. The only other issue now seem to be from the monster.yaml format. but with nothing in the file, the errors vanish. I will now test my stuff :-)

Comment: @Cris external libraries generally install to /usr/local for a very good reason - so as to not clash with system libraries. You can add /usr/local/lib to your library path by simply adding it to ld.so.conf (or, on Ubuntu, creating a file ending with .conf with the directory /usr/local/lib in it in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/)

Comment: Unless you're a gentoo user, in which case everything is compiled by source and /usr/local is basically the leper colony of installs.

Comment: @Chris, I actually found an even cleaner way of pre-loading 'custom' libraries, by using the `ldconfig` command to configure the library search path after i add the path to my libs into a `*.conf` file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find the yaml-cpp headers. First of all, the include directive should be

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
```

since, as you can see, the headers are installed to `/usr/local/include/yaml-cpp/`.

Do you get an error message on the line of the include statement? (Can you post the full compiler output?)

Comment: yes, I did run the `make` and the `sudo make install`, but still got problems!

Comment: I have added the output from the make commands, what do you think is wrong?

Comment: there, I've pasted part of the compiler output (it was way too much than i could put here!), but I've only included part of the start and end of this output. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @mcnemesis, so just to clarify: is the first line of the compiler output `error: 'YAML' does not name a type`? What I'm looking for is, is the compiler happy with the line `#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"`?